# Getting Mat picture from camera in OpenCV for Android

Tags: opencv, android

I have a little bit of experience in OpenCV for Python and C, but zero in Java especially in Android Studio. Now, I want to make an app using openCV.

Can somebody teach me how to open camera, capture the image, and then return the image in Mat type for later processing ?

I'm sorry if this has been asked before. I've searched for answers, but am never satisfied with the answer/code I encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like this:

```
public class yourclass extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
Mat mRgba;
Mat mGray;

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    mGray.release();
}
/* this is the important part */
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Log.i(TAG,"onCameraFrame before inputFrame");
    Mat rgb;
    int red =rgb[0], green=rgb[1], blue=rgb[2];
    return rgb;
}
```